# Use API response into another component - React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am newer in React JS.
I am using functional based components, I have a popup component(Registration.js) and after filling the form it gets response from REST API. Now, I need to show an another popup component(Alert.js) and update the data into popup according to response.

Comment: have you tried passing data through child props?

Comment: @Awais Thanks for replying.
I am not sure how to do that. Can you share some references?

Comment: If you dont know how to pass props til child components then i *strongly* suggest reading the reactjs docs and tutorials.